# Parent and child classes casting

Tags: java, casting, parent, extends, children

I have been wondering if i have this structure for example

```
Class Parent{
   parentMethod1...
}
Class Child extends Parent{
   childMethod1()...
   childMethod2()...
}
Class OtherClass{
   public Parent parent;
}
Class OtherClassChild extends OtherClass{
   public Child child;
   /* we need to use methodChild1();

}
```

So my question is : Is it better to have public Child child in OtherClassChild or just cast the parent instance from the OtherClass ?(and i am sure that the instance in my case is always of the child so there will be no exeption thrown ?

Comment: This is sort of an opinion question, but reducing casting would be the better way to go.

Comment: I see. Thanks and i tend to agree with you.Other question does casting parent to child create a new  reference of the child class ? so everytime i cast a new reference is created ?

Comment: No, it would be the same reference. You must remember, though, that you can't cast a `Parent` reference to a `Child` reference, but if you have a `Parent` reference variable holding a `Child` reference, the reference variable can be casted. Try to avoid `ClassCastExceptions` at all costs.

Comment: I got you . Thanks